# how to put text between commas automatically python

Tags: python

Okay so I made a script in python that scrapes data from a website and prints it but it prints like this

[image]

but I want it to output like this:

```
283049610,5785985,93709266
```

this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

path = 'C:\chromedriver'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=options)

driver.get('website')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find('div', {'class': 'mix_container'})
for item in items.find_all('div', {'data-ref': 'item'}):
    print(re.search('\d+', item.find('a')['href']).group())
```

Comment: `",".join(map(str, <sequence>))` where sequence is any iterable set of numbers

Comment: format your output using **f' '**  or  **' '.format()**

Comment: `print(sep=',')`

Comment: `print(stre.search('\d+', item.find('a')['href']).group()r1,end=',')`